# mysql how to search three field in database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to user to search each field separate or two fields, or all three according to want he/she want (all are in the same table)

Example1:  user can select gender `MALE` status “PAID”

Example2:  user can select status `paid` Renewal_status `NOT RENEWAL`

Example3:  user can select gender `female` Renewal_status `NOT RENEWAL` and etc.

Here is my codes:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM member 
    WHERE Gender='$advocate_gender' 
    OR Status='$advocate_pcstatus' 
    OR Renewal_status='$renewal_status' 
    ORDER BY RollNo ";
```

Comment: Just dynamically build your where clause based off the filters your user actually needs.  Don't have a set where clause with a bunch of "OR"s because what happens when they want it filtered on two or three conditions?  You'll pull everything that has at least one condition even the results that don't include all 2 or 3 filters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a technique to use the parameters in one query. Like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
          FROM member 
         WHERE Gender = coalesce('$advocate_gender',Gender)
           AND Status = coalesce('$advocate_pcstatus', Status) 
           AND Renewal_status = coalesce('$renewal_status', Renewal_status) 
         ORDER BY RollNo ";
```

But be aware that `''` (empty) is not equal to `NULL` that what the function `coalesce` will check, if the parameter passed is null it will replace it for the next argument, so if you pass `$advocate_gender` as `null` the `where` filter will yields to Gender = Gender which is always true.

Also I changed the `OR` by `AND` it will make more sense but if you want to check for one or other field just change it.

Since I said to you that `''` (empty) is not equal to `NULL` you should consider in using prepared statements so the language will take care of the parameter to you, in the end the query will be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
          FROM member 
         WHERE Gender = coalesce( ?, Gender)
           AND Status = coalesce( ?, Status) 
           AND Renewal_status = coalesce( ?, Renewal_status) 
         ORDER BY RollNo ";
```

Depending on what library you are using just pass the parameters see the [PDO reference](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) as one of then

Comment: Thanks @JorgeCampos, I try your codes with AND but need to fill all three field,by using OR not bring true answer , its display all members, I need to search  either one only, two or three .

Comment: Then you definitely needs the AND clause.

Answer (score 1):

You need dynamically build the sql:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM member WHERE 1=1';

if ($advocate_gender) $sql .= " AND Gender='$advocate_gender'";
if ($advocate_pcstatus) $sql .= " AND Status='$advocate_pcstatus'";
if ($renewal_status) $sql .= " AND Renewal_status='$renewal_status'"; 
$sql .= ' ORDER BY RollNo';
```

Comment: Thank you @SIDU but I'm not good in mysql or PHP, please can you put clear according to my field name ?

Comment: Hi I have updated the reply based on your original question.